# Sitecore 9.1 Dynamics Marketing List to XConnect Sync pipeline

Tags: xconnect, pipelines

Dynamics Marketing List sync in 8.2 is inbuilt pipeline and works for our requirement.It looks like that functionality is removed in 9.1 and we need to create our own pipeline for marketing list sync.

I have created the pipelines and batch based on https://www.clearpeople.com/insights/blog/2019/january/how-to-synchronise-dynamics-crm-marketing-lists-into-sitecore-9

While running the batch pipeline I get the below error, Kindly help.

> ManagedPoolThread #6 11:50:32 INFO [Data Exchange] Starting pipeline
>   batch processing. (pipeline batch: Dynamics Marketing Lists to
>   Sitecore Items)
>
> ---
>
> ManagedPoolThread #6 11:50:53 INFO [Data Exchange] Entities were read from Dynamics. (pipeline: Read
>   CRM List Pipeline, pipeline step: Read CRM Marketing Lists, pipeline
>   step identifier: 31ffabeb-863c-4ecc-af04-4e7e418ad094, endpoint:
>   Dynamics Organization Endpoint, entity: list)
>
> ---
>
> ManagedPoolThread #6 11:50:54 ERROR [Data Exchange] No value was read from identifier object.
>   (pipeline: CRM List to Sitecore Item Sync Pipeline, pipeline step:
>   Resolve Sitecore Item, pipeline step identifier:
>   c6df2e1f-0c4f-4aaa-b073-280105b5170c)
>
> ---
>
> ManagedPoolThread #6 11:50:54 ERROR [Data Exchange] No identifier value was resolved. (pipeline: CRM
>   List to Sitecore Item Sync Pipeline, pipeline step: Resolve Sitecore
>   Item, pipeline step identifier: c6df2e1f-0c4f-4aaa-b073-280105b5170c)

Can anybody help?